# Error while fetching data from Office365 using EWS.dll

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I am trying to fetch Office365 user account emails using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. But I am getting intermittent error while load data request. The load request for email appears to be stuck or it will throws the exception.

Here is my sample code:

```
_ExchnageService.KeepAlive = true;

PropertySet objProperty = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent);

_Item.Load(objProperty ); // Some times load request didn't respond for hours which appears to be stuck. 

//And some times it thorws following exeption
```

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The
>   request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsUtilities.CopyStream(Stream
>   source, Stream target)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse
>   response)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse
>   response)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalLoadPropertiesForItems(IEnumerable`1
>   items, PropertySet propertySet, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalLoad(PropertySet
>   propertySet)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObject.Load(PropertySet
>   propertySet)    at
>   CDT.Office365Reader.DownloadO365Mails.RetriveO365MailValues(Item
>   p_obj_Item, FolderID folderId, String p_FolderPath, ExchangeService
>   p_ExchnageService, String p_username)

Any help or suggestion on this issue is greatly appreciated.